# Visual Studio Database Project - Use SQLCMD variable to define File size

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, database-project

Does anybody knows if it is possible to use SQLCMD variables to define the size? I'm trying with this:

```
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
ADD FILE (
    NAME = [MyFile_1],
    FILENAME = N'$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_MyFile_1.ndf', 
    SIZE = $(FileSize) MB, 
    FILEGROWTH = $(FileGrowth) MB )
TO FILEGROUP [MyFileGroup];
```

But Receive the following errors when try to build the solution:

```
SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near '$'.  Expecting ID, INTEGER, QUOTED_ID, STRING, or TEXT_LEX.
SQL46010: Incorrect syntax near $(FileSize).
SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near 'FileSize'. 
SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near 'FileGrowth'.  Expecting '(', or SELECT.
```

Variables are defined in the project configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me.  It looks like you are missing a closing quote after the file name.  That is, you have

```
FILENAME = N'$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_MyFile_1.ndf,
```

but should have

```
FILENAME = N'$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_MyFile_1.ndf',
```

Also, have you verified that there are setvar's at the top of your publish script, e.g.

```
:setvar FileSize "1024"
:setvar FileSize "10"
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo when I changed the file name (it was a long and useless name) but the original code is OK. I cannot verify the the SETVAR's sentences since the project does not build, so it does not create the publish script.